# Running queries against multiple servers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to use a Central Management Server, with a server group underneith, to run management queries against multiple server.

I know how to run a query against the whole group through SSMS, but I want to schedule queries to run through server agent.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for it sounds like is the Target Servers of a job. You can add your servers to this portion so that the job is run against your desired servers.

BOL documentation on Target Servers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189553.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I though about this, but I want to save the results to a table on the "Master Server". From what I understand, this will not work, baring in mind I cannot create linked servers. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @Pete why can you not create linked servers?

Comment: @PeteCarter I'm with Aaron on this one.  Why can't you create linked servers??

Comment: @AaronBertrand & Thomas - I can't use linked servers because of unfounded security concerns. I may need to resort to SSIS I guess

Comment: If these people think linked servers are a security concern, how are you going to convince them that SSIS is some perfectly safe magic? You should counteract with truth, not kludges IMHO.

Comment: Another possibility is to write a PowerShell script and using SMO do all of this logic, then just call the script from a SQL Server Agent job.

Comment: @ThomasStringer Powershell script a great idea thanks

Comment: @AaronBertrand the infrastructure concern is that what I am writing is essentially a different application, and from both seurity and architecture any link between apps should be loosly coupled, ideally through Biztalk. This is increased because an external team will be supporting the main app. I can convince SSIS (or PS as Thoas suggested) because it "kind of" fits this model, where as Linked Servers are synchronous and as far as infrastructure would be concerned, turn the main app into a landing zone. Additionally, I need a way to "plug-in" additional servers with minimal effort.

Answer (score 3):

Management Studio is the glue that makes that work. To use SQL Server Agent you'd have to set up Target Servers manually as Thomas suggested, or add [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and manually loop through each server in your job step(s).

Note that your local CMS may have access to servers that your server might not (e.g. consider the scenario where most of your managed servers are in the data center, but you also have dev/test servers in the local domain - you can manage all of these from the client tools on your desktop but probably not from the data center).